# Merge two methods into one with ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to **merge two methods** `a()` and `b()` instructions into a method `c()` that I created through `new MethodNode()`
Is there an easy way to do that in asm without breaking line numbers, labels, etc?

Simply adding instructions of both into one insnlist seems to cause issues while reading the class

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a new method `c` that simply *calls* `a` and `b` one after the other? I expect doing what you to do be distinctly non-trivial, as you'll have to make sure the verifier accepts the result, which can be tricky.

Comment: The execution of a method’s code is not allowed to fall off the code at the end. So a valid instruction sequence always ends with a return instruction, `athrow`, or a backward `goto`. Appending another instruction sequence to such a sequence does nothing but create unreachable code. I suppose, you’re not calculating stackmap frames by hand, as that requires awareness of  such issues. When you don’t use the `COMPUTE_FRAMES` option, the code will be invalid due to the missing initial stack frame. When you use it, ASM will replace unreachable code with `nop`s, as it can’t predict its initial fame

Comment: In short, you can not simple concatenate instruction sequences. You’d need to replace first’s return instruction with the second instruction sequence. All assuming that you’re talking about parameterless `void` methods, as otherwise, things are far more complicated.